# How to run a Vite React app from a subfolder

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, vite

I use Vite to create a React app.

Routes.tsx

```
import { RouteObject, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../layout/App";
import HomePage from "../../feautures/home/HomePage";
import CreateRegistration from "../../feautures/createRegistration/createRegistration";

export const routes: RouteObject[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <App />,
        children: [
            { path: '', element: <HomePage /> },
            { path: 'createRegistrationForm', element: <CreateRegistration /> }
        ]
    }
];

export const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);
```

In my vite.config.ts I have

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  //base: '/registration/',
  server:{
    port: 3000
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

and everything works great at `"http://127.0.0.1:3000/"` but the moment in my `vite.config.ts` when I uncomment `base: '/registration/',` and go to `"http://127.0.0.1:3000/registration/"`  I get all 404 errors for all routes. I'm not sure what I am missing to run a React app using Vite in a subfolder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The piece that I believe is missing is setting a [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#basename) value for the `BrowserRouter` to match where it's routing/navigating relative to.

> The basename of the app for situations where you can't deploy to the
> root of the domain, but a sub directory.

The `basename` passed to the router should match the Vite configuration.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/registration/',
  server:{
    port: 3000
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

```
export const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <HomePage /> },
      { path: 'createRegistrationForm', element: <CreateRegistration /> }
    ]
  }
];

export const router = createBrowserRouter(routes, {
  basename: "/registration/",
});
```